# Is there a non language specific general help chat room?

Tags: discussion, new-users, chat

I was reading through the Mentors part of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384169/help-us-identify-new-roles-for-community-members?cb=1).

I'm wondering if there's a sort of new user help room for new contributors to get help on how to ask questions and write answers. I know you have to have at least 20 rep to chat, but it isn't that hard to get 20 rep if a new user is actually spending time and trying to contribute to the community. I think it would be good to have something like this, which would actually decrease the amount of fluff on SO, and it would serve as a helpful alternative solution to flagging, downvoting, moving on and forgetting about it.

I'm not saying that there aren't new users who are purely focused on getting an answer and who won't bother to use the help room, just saying that it would (might? I know I would have been grateful for one of those) benefit new users who actually want to learn to be a good member of the SO community.

(Feel free to downvote if you don't agree. If by chance this is actually a good idea, I'll start the chat room.)

Comment: I dont fully understand your idea. There are already rooms for languages to get help and disscuse. [C#](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c), [java](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java), [PHP](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), [JS](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), [Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), [R](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) and [C++](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) just on the first page.

Comment: No, I wasn't thinking about getting help on a specific language. I was thinking about a chat room specifically on how to ask good questions and write good answers.

Comment: The staging groud will help with that. And there is a closed beta going on for it right now and they said it will be release ~Febuary I belive

Comment: There were [similar attempts here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227446/edit-support-for-reopening). But none really materialized. Maybe you could start one(after getting a no objection from moderators)?

Comment: FWIW, since many questions  focus on a single language it is often fine to seek asking advice on the respective language channel. That also helps to get better feedback on scoring peculiarities and duplicates.

Comment: @TheMaster good idea, but how would I find out if the moderators like it or not?

Comment: You can ping them in comments or chat. But I would probably start a room first and gauge interest and feasibility. If there are issues, moderators will contact you.

Comment: Just for the record: In SOCVR we explicitly forbid requests for posts you're involved. We have added that rule because the motivation of an OP for improving their post is often different from the site goal. An OP want their post to be answered and/or well received while curators want a (high) quality addition to the body of knowledge that Stackoverflow needs to be. If you manage in your room to convey the essence of "helping" new contributors to participate in building the knowledge base your room might be useful.  ... <cont>

Comment: ... <cont> Otherwise it will become an arena where disgruntled new users can vent their frustration and toxicity and that is not a fun place to be in when as an expert you're spending your free-time

Comment: @rene yeah I understand that. I might put the chat room on my profile and start directing higher than 20-rep new users asking unclear questions there. (Unless that's forbidden.) Would it be fine just to leave a comment explaining the problem with their question and directing them to the chat room?